# Not calling PHP file from Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Requirement: I have a php file, it generates Excel with data from MySQL. I want to call it from my form.

Problem: When I call it from HTML, it downloads normally without any issue, but when I call it from Angular it is not getting downloaded.

Firstly I am showing you my simple html code below of `download.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<form action="exportData.php" method="get">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Now below is my Angular/Ionic code:

`home.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    <ion-title>View Complaint Open / Close</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="showdata()">{{c_status}}</button>
      <button ion-button icon-only  (click)="downldexcl()" type="submit" title="Download Excel File">
        <ion-icon  name="ios-download-outline" class="top-icon"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

`home.ts`

```
import { UserProvider } from '../../providers/user/user';

...//some code 
  downldexcl()
{
  this.user.exlDwnld().subscribe(datac => {
      console.log(datac,"list");
      console.log(datac);
      //document.location.href = this.user._url+"download.php?file="+datac;
    });
}
```

`user.ts`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response,Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {LoadingController, ToastController, ModalController, AlertController} from "ionic-angular";

...//some code 
    exlDwnld()
      {
       // let params1_c = '&t1label=' + t1label+'&t1data=' +encodeURIComponent(t1data)+'&h1colnum=' + h1colnum+'&t2label=' + t2label+'&t2data=' + encodeURIComponent(t2data)+'&h2colnum=' + h2colnum+'&total1=' + total1+'&total2=' + total2+'&fromdt=' + fromdt+'&todt=' + todt+'&filename=' + filename+'&topheader=' + topheader+'&subheader1=' + subhead1+'&subheader2=' + subhead2;
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this._http.post(this._url + "exportData.php", {headers: headers})
          .map((response: Response) => response.json());
      }
```

Why on clicking the button from Ionic/Angular page, the Excel is not getting downloaded.

Comment: What is your console logging for `datac`?

Comment: it is showing the data, https://prnt.sc/pcpaju

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like `exportData.php` is returning raw tsv data? You probably don't want to be mapping that to json, and you would need to actually do something with it in the response. If you wanted it to behave similarly to the basic html example you could replace the http client with something like `window.open(this._url + "exportData.php?" + params)` - this should just open the php file directly like the form submit would have in the html example

Answer (score 0):

You are using the post request method in angular instead of get. Try chaning that.

```
return this._http.post(this._url + "exportData.php", {headers: headers})
```

to

```
return this._http.get(this._url + "exportData.php", {headers: headers})
```

That should do the trick.

Also you are using the old http module, import the new HttpClientModule from '@angular/common/http'

and remove the map to response.json, the new module does that for you.

Comment: done as you guided , but still excel is not getting downloaded, see me response - https://prnt.sc/pcrjtq , we have installed the new HttpClientModule  aswell, updating my question, please let me know what do i do next